# Is a typedef in base class visible in inherited class without being fully qualified?

Tags: c++, templates, inheritance

**Example**

```
template <typename T>
struct A
{
    typedef A<T> super;
};

template <typename T>
struct B : A<T>
{
    B() : super() {} // <-- HERE
};

int main()
{
}
```

With the MSVC compiler, this compiles as-is. However with gcc, I need to change `super()` to `A<T>::super()`. I'm assuming gcc is correct here, however could someone help me understand the rule here and which compiler is technically correct?

Comment: What.. are you trying to do with this `typedef`?

Comment: Note that you can also write `B::super()` if that helps.

Comment: @KirilKirov: It's more of a convenience feature than anything, derived classes could you `super` without having to declare it (my example is somewhat poor though).

Comment: @KirilKirov: If the base type has tons of template parameters, you normally do not want to repeat yourself. A couple of boost classes also provide a `base_type` typedef, for example Boost.Spirit's `grammar` class, as seen [here](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_41_0/libs/spirit/doc/html/spirit/qi/reference/nonterminal/grammar.html) (`my_grammar() : my_grammar::base_type(start, name)`).

Comment: @Xeo - thanks. This is interesting, I didn't know it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, since it's a dependant name, since `A` is a class template. You need to either fully qualify it, or use a shortcut `B::super`. The latter will also tell the compiler that it's a dependant name and is very handy if the derived class also has lots of template parameters, since `B` will expand to `B<T, and, stuff>` since it's the *injected class name*.

MSVC is wrong here thanks to its incomplete two-phase lookup. Basically, with MSVC, all the dependency checks and stuff only happen during instantiation of the template, while it should have been checked at declaration.

Comment: Nice, didn't know about the shortcut which will help a lot since the actual class has quite a few template parameters.

Comment: BTW, the reason why a plain `super()` is invalid is because things get really complicated if you add specialisations of `A` that lack the `super` typedef.

Comment: @hvd: That applies to all dependant names, it's exactly *why* they're called "dependant". ;)